# Safari detecting the user is scrolling down when at the top of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have the following code which hides the header when a user is scrolling down and reveals the header when the user is scrolling up.

It seems to work fine apart from in Safari, in Safari when you scroll to the top of a page the header is being hidden when it shouldnt be.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var position = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > position) {
        $(".site-header").removeClass("transparent");
        $(".footer-inner").removeClass("hide");
      } else {
        $(".site-header").addClass("transparent");
        $(".footer-inner").addClass("hide");
      }
      position = scroll;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that comment.

Comment: Did you try to debug it and see why it isn't working? try logging the numbers so you can see where things went wrong

Comment: It is always tricky to work with things like scrolling or client window size in different browsers. As mentioned above, try to debug (or console.log) it and understand what are `position` and `scroll` after it loads, and after you scroll down.

Comment: ok thanks, il give it a try

Comment: I can see that in Safari the scroll variable is going into minus numbers when at the top of the page which I believe is causing the issue. Is there a way to edit my code so the header is visible if the scroll variable is 0 or above ?

Comment: The only way _around_ that is if you lock the body (aka wrap everything in an element yourself and setting your body to `overflow:hidden`). However, is not possible to just ignore it if the scrollValue is smaller than 0?

Comment: oh ok, so i cant just say if scroll = 0 then show header ? or something similar